# Android correct Radiobutton layout in group

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, radiobuttonlist, radio-group

I've created a RadioGroup with the following RadioButtons **with the layout I want to achieve**.

[image: Radiobuttons]

XML hierarchy:

- RadioGroup

  - LinearLayout

    - RadioButton
    - RadioButton
  - LinearLayout

    - RadioButton
    - RadioButton
  - RadioButton

Of course this means only 1 RadioButton is still a direct child of the RadioGroup, which means that when I click any of the RadioButtons, the one who was already checked doesn't uncheck.

I'm using a very compact code to obtain the checked RadioButton, if they were direct childs.

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.rgTopupValue);
View radioCheckedView = rg.findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) rg.getChildAt(rg.indexOfChild(radioCheckedView));
```

Is there a way to solve the problem, **without the use of extremely long cases**?

Comment: please make it a bit clear.. i didn't got if you want to have all the radio buttons function as they are from same group or what ??

Comment: Preferably yes, but that's impossible. I haven't found my exact answer in any case. Google should make it easier to layout RadioButtons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like there is no real answer to your question. I don't think there is a real solution. But this might solve your problem (it's a workaround):

```
    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb3);

    rb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rb1.setChecked(true);
            rb2.setChecked(false);
            rb3.setChecked(false);
        }
    });

    rb2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rb1.setChecked(false);
            rb2.setChecked(true);
            rb3.setChecked(false);
        }
    });

    rb3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rb1.setChecked(false);
            rb2.setChecked(false);
            rb3.setChecked(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid this might be the only way it can be done. Shame it's so long though.

Comment: It's not that long, but why do you want it to be as short as posible?

Comment: I don't know, I guess it's a personal preference.
As RadioGroups are LinearLayouts, could I use those nested in? That way I might be able to uncheck 2 RadioButtons at once (in my case)

Comment: Yes, you can. And you can also atleast upvote me for the afford ;)